# Who is the "Floyd County" woman shown during the credits of Archer?

Tags: identify-this-actor, archer

During the credits of many episodes of Archer, a photo of a middle-aged blonde woman leaning on a table, possibly at a bar or diner, is shown.  The woman seems physically reminiscent of, but is not identical to, the Archer character named Pam.

The name of the production company, "Floyd County", appears and the phrase, "Made... in Georgia." is spoken.

Who is this woman (or what is the source for this image) and, if possible, why was this image used?

Screen capture:

[image: screencap of the Floyd County image]

Comment: She looks like Courtney love to me.

Comment: Always wanted to post that question here when i watch an episode of archer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The photo was taken by Kevin Russ, and is found in his Flickr account on Page 7 of "People 2006", which lists [all her photos](https://www.flickr.com/photos/pattersonminx/sets/72157594197316323/page7/).

She is referred to as "Melody".

Evidence from the Flickr account include 
[photo a](https://www.flickr.com/photos/pattersonminx/255444967/in/set-72157594197316323), [photo b](https://www.flickr.com/photos/pattersonminx/255444966/in/set-72157594197316323), [photo c](https://www.flickr.com/photos/pattersonminx/255444962/in/set-72157594197316323), and [photo d](https://www.flickr.com/photos/pattersonminx/255109293/in/set-72157594197316323).  Here are some photos from the group, all rights reserved for Kevin Russ.

[image: scale]
[image: scale]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

The second photo states it is of the photographer himself with "Melody".

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: @Dreadedsemicolon Do you know why WHAT?

Comment: Why they decided to show this photo, what's her relationship to the show? sorry if i missed the connection.

Answer (score 7):

I did some digging and found 2 forums ([here](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=601837) and [here](http://www.closinglogos.com/thread/5085703/Floyd+County+Productions+and+Great+Scott+Films+International)) where this picture was discussed.  The posts state that this image came from a stock photo site, *istockphoto.*

Though there was a link in the discussions to support the findings, the link no longer works, so I cannot prove that the image came from *istockphoto.*  Nonetheless, the multiple discussion threads give me quite the confidence that the image was pulled from a stock photo site.

Comment: Found this by googling for 'tired older blonde woman in a motor home': http://www.spiderpic.com/stock-photos/istockphoto/2224871-tired-older-blonde-woman-in-a-motorhome

Comment: It is the photo taken by Kevin Russ, per the answer by @Samwatkins.